# Rails app (Redmine) on Phusion Passenger is very slow on first request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, redmine

I've recently deployed a Redmine app (production env) on an AWS server and every time I go to the page after a delay (10+ minues), it take a painfully long time for the page to load. 
After googling for the cause of this, I've stumbled upon a passenger setting PassengerPoolIdleTime which I've set to 0. Based on my limited understanding of what this setting does, it is supposed to keep my site always running and should not be spinning any more threads. I've added this setting to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, but it did not help.
I've also added a PassengerMinInstances to my VirtualHost directive, but all to no avail.

Could someone please help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the CPU utilization on your server when it becomes really slow?  Can you post outputs for `top` and `uptime` when the server is slow ?  Are you using a t1.micro instance ? if yes, can you try a bigger instance it could be that your micro instance is being oversubscribed.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I am running t1.micro. Here's the header of top: top - 18:32:34 up 3 days,  8:33,  2 users,  load average: 0.77, 0.26, 0.13
Tasks:  87 total,   1 running,  86 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  6.7%us,  3.0%sy,  0.3%ni,  0.0%id, 90.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    604344k total,   597128k used,     7216k free,      540k buffers
Swap:  1048572k total,   297680k used,   750892k free,    13608k cached
Maxim CPU consumption reach 10% for system and 2% for user. What do you mean by "oversubscribed"?